# PHP CURL not connecting to correct IP address

Tags: php, curl, ip, plesk, traceroute

I have a PHP script that should get a page from a domain www.example.com.

The script is run from a Plesk 11.5 server that hosts subdomains of example.com, but not the www.example.com domain itself. The server is configured for the explicit subdomains only, no wildcard *.example.com stuff.

When doing a ping or traceroute from the subdomain.example.com server to the www.example.com domain, it returns the correct IP address.

When trying to do a curl request (either command line or from PHP), it tries to connect to the local server instead.

Does anybody know what might be the problem?

Comment: Does the same script works fine on your localhost ?

Comment: Have you tried using the IP with cURL and not the domain?

Comment: I think, problem in configuration of /etc/hosts

Comment: @Loïc; seems to connect, but returns a "default" page. Perhaps the problem is in the configuration of the receiving server. wget returns same wrong page. In a browser everything works fine.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran works fine on localhost